# Are there RWeka's Detailed Accuracy By Class?

Tags: r, machine-learning, weka, rweka

In [Weka 3.8.3](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) (a machine learning platform), the results of an analysis using JRip classifier are in the following form.

```
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         158               25.2396 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       468               74.7604 %
Kappa statistic                          0.0004
Mean absolute error                      0.3743
Root mean squared error                  0.4365
Relative absolute error                 99.7998 %
Root relative squared error            100.7977 %
Total Number of Instances              626    

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.166     0.162      0.255     0.166     0.201      0.504    A
                 0         0          0         0         0          0.464    B
                 0.006     0.009      0.2       0.006     0.012      0.526    C
                 0.829     0.829      0.252     0.829     0.387      0.499    D
Weighted Avg.    0.252     0.252      0.177     0.252     0.151      0.498

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   d   <-- classified as
  26   0   1 130 |   a = A
  31   0   1 123 |   b = B
  20   0   1 135 |   c = C
  25   0   2 131 |   d = D
```

With [RWeka 0.4-40](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html) (Weka for R), the same kind of analysis produces results in the following form.

```
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         203               32.4281 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       423               67.5719 %
Kappa statistic                          0.0966
Mean absolute error                      0.3605
Root mean squared error                  0.4246
Relative absolute error                 96.1482 %
Root relative squared error             98.0552 %
Total Number of Instances              626     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   d   <-- classified as
  41   0   3 113 |   a = A
  12   0   5 138 |   b = B
   7   0  23 126 |   c = C
   9   0  10 139 |   d = D
```

Where's the data of the "Detailed Accuracy By Class" section (the second section from the original Weka results)? I've tried

```
library(RWeka)
library(caret)
TrainData <- p[,2:211]
TrainClasses <- p[,215]
jripFit <- train(TrainData,TrainClasses,method='JRip')
jripFit
summary(jripFit)
str(jripFit)
```

but it's nowhere to be found. Obviously, `p` is my data.frame, and 215th column is the classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the `caret` package.

```
library(RWeka)
jripFit <- JRip(myClass ~ ., data = p[,c(2:211,215)])
summary(jripFit,class=T)
```

where `myClass` is the name of the 215th column of `p`, which must be a factor (while columns 2 to 211 are numeric).

Another point of interest: `JRip` function was 663 (!) times faster than the `train` function, at least on my machine.